# How to read a file using the redirected standard input, i.e. cin(Note:without using ifstream)

Tags: c++

Plus: I redirected standard input by editing the command argumennts in property pages in VS2013. I'm doing a small project and it requires I read a file without using the ifstream cause it's said: The only libraries you may use for this assignment are iostream, iomanip, and string.

Comment: `std::cin >> i`, `std::getline(std::cin)`, etc. Check out what `istream`s can do: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Comment: modifying the property pages isn't an ideal way of doing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When file is redirected to *stdin* (standard input), you should read from `std::cin` (instance of `std::istream`) which is wrapper around stdin. `std::basic_ifstream` is a subclass of `std::basic_istream`, so most reading functions are available in both of them and you should familiar with them. Which means that you can use:

- `std::getline` to read file line by line:

  ```
  std::string s;
  while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- `operator >>` to read fields delimited by space character:

  ```
  while(std::cin) {
      std::string s;
      std::cin >> s;
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
  ```

Check out full list of its operators and functions here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer that I want ! Thank u really very much! ! !

Comment: hardly answers the question. The question is about redirection not reading from istreams

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect *cin* to a file and for that you need to set the stream buffer associated with cin using

> ios::rdbuf()

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/)

and a couple more on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407077/read-from-cin-or-a-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Answer (score -1):

You can use "freopen" functionn. Example:

> freopen("input.txt","r",stdin).

That means you read a file "input.txt" and save it's contents to "stdin". Now, you can use "cin".

Comment: This doesn't  answer the question (freopen doesn't _read_ file) and uses C library (while question is explicitly tagged C++)

Comment: So, how can you read data from file by using std::cin >> i, std::getline(std::cin), without opening file?

Comment: `./a.out < file.txt` That is what is called file input redirection: http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never know that before.